# Coordinate vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the vector x $\in$ $\mathbb{R^3}$ whose coordinates with respect to the basis $$B = \{(-2,2,2),(3,-2,3),(2,-1,1)\}$$ are

$[x]_B = [2;1;1].$

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes i tried using the inverse way to solve it but didn't get the write solution.

Comment: What do you mean by the inverse way? The inverse of the matrix $B$?

Comment: yes that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

Let $e_1, e_2, e_3$ be the basis vectors in $B$. Then you can express a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with respect to this basis as
$$ v = v^1 e_1 + v^2 e_2 + v^3 e_3,$$
where $v^1, v^2, v^3$ are the components of $v$. We abbreviate this by writing
$$[v]_B = [v^1 ; v^2 ; v^3].$$
It should be obvious how to proceed from here, since you are told what $e_1, e_2, e_3$ are.